# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{r^n \cdot \sqrt n \cdot \arctan{\frac{1}{n+1}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have to find for which $r\in\mathbb{R}$ a) series diverge b)converge absolutely c)converge not absolutely. $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{r^n \cdot \sqrt n \cdot \arctan{\frac{1}{n+1}}}$$
I don't know what(and how) tests to use while $r$ is there. I can only see that $\lim a_n\not=0$ for $r>1$and therefore for such r the series diverge.

Comment: Use the Ratio Test. The ratio of the arctans has limit $1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Interesting, I got that $lim a_{n+1}/a_n = r$ so for $|r|>1$ the series is divergent and if $|r|<1$ is absolutely convergent. I don't have to worry about non absolute convergence?

Comment: You do have to worry about what happens at $r=1$ and $r=-1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Oh right, so for $r=1$ I use limit comparison test with $1/\sqrt{n}$ so series diverge. And for $r=-1$ I am little bit stuck as I don't know how to prove sequence is non increasing

Comment: All that matters is what happens in the long run. Looking at the derivative should show you the function is ultimately decreasing, so we get convergence at $r=-1$.

Comment: Ah, I see now, thank you for helping me step by step, if you transform some of your hints into answer I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: You are welcome. The whole point was to help you find the answer. Anyway, it is time to go to sleep.